# Wrap string after special character Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this string in my HTML document :

```
<dd class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-2-3976">
An awesomephoto © goodjobstudio</dd>
```

In Jquery, I want to wrap into span this part of the string :  `© goodjobstudio`

So I try this in Jquery :

```
str = $('.slider-for .gallery-item .wp-caption-text').text();
str.replace(/(©)+/gi, '<span>$1</span>');
```

But it does not work

Thanks for your help !

Comment: _“But it does not work”_ - it _did_ work, you are just _not doing anything_ with the result. `var newValue = str.replace(...); $('.slider-for .gallery-item .wp-caption-text').html(newValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `substring` should be faster and easier.

```js
let str = "An awesomephoto © goodjobstudio"
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('©')).trim();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: use console.log instead of alert() @baao it doesn't provide an solution to this question

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, please try to concentrate on important things when commenting @jasinthpremkumar

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should do:

```
let str = $('.wp-caption-text').html();
$('.wp-caption-text').html(str.replace(/(©)+/gi, '<span>$1</span>'));
console.log($('.wp-caption-text').html());
```